# UWP: The type 'TreeView' was not found; on a project targeting Fall Creators Update Build 16299

Tags: uwp

I put a

```
<TreeView></TreeView>
```

on a Page, but these erros appears:

> TreeView is not supported in a Windows Universal project.
>
> The type 'TreeView' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an
>   assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.
>
> Unknown type 'TreeView' in XML namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'

On the Project this is set:

```
<TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.16299.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
```

[image: Project properties]

**How to use the TreeView (and HierarchicalDataTemplate) in a UWP Project?**

Answer (score 3):

`TreeView` control was originally planned for the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update, but was scraped from the release in the end. It is believed this happened because to have this control properly supported, `HierarchicalDataTemplate` should be introduced to UWP first to have a proper support for data binding and templating the control.

However, the current version of the source code, which is compatible with Fall Creators Update and is implemented using `ListView` is [available on `GitHub`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlTreeView), so you can include it in your project manually. It is built as a C++ Windows Runtime Component, which means it is compatible with all Windows Runtime languages including C#.

Comment: I hope they complete the TreeView control, all features, including HierarchicalDataTemplate, and control of Drag/Drop options, etc., and include it on UWP (no need to compile the C++ sources in my solution)

Comment: I am pretty sure they will. It was already a part of the preview SDKs before it was scraped. It should be part of the next release.

Comment: See https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/issues/835#issuecomment-361298142

Answer (score 0):

**TreeView** is now included on the Windows 10 build 17134 (also known as the April Update or version 1803)

So we can target this version and then use this XAML:

```
<TreeView></TreeView>
```

It does not seem to support `HierarchicalDataTemplate` yet.

See the annoucement:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/whats-new/windows-10-build-17134

TreeView documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tree-view